# Bind reactive form data into string with interpolation

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, kendo-ui

I have an object with a string property: [image]

This property contains a string with interpolation like this: [image]

In my UI I use a reactive form with an input field, when the user provides the data I would like this string to appear under the form with the data written like this this: [image]

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

I have tried multiple ideas, but I'm still learning a lot about Angular so any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: `I have tried multiple ideas` What have you tried so far? You could simply bind the same property in your string as the property bound to your input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reference variable #port in the input field

```
<input #port placeholder="port...">
<span>ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT {{port.value}}</span>
```

in the TS file use

```
@ViewChild('port') port : ElementRef;

class SomeCmp implements AfterViewInit {

ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=''
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT= this.port.nativeElement.value
  }
}
```